# Auth0 Passwordless to new email address

Tags: auth0

I have users with passwordless access via Auth0. I want to add a feature where they can update their email address. Before updating the address I want them to confirm a passwordless code that is sent to the **new** email, not the current one.

It appears I can't send a passwordless code to an arbitrary email address without creating a new account for it.

My plan is to update the email address in Auth0, then send the passwordless code request, then update the email address back. Once the code is verified I will update the email address permanently.

Is this the correct flow? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: I'm not an expert in [Auth0 service](https://auth0.com/); but, if I were to do that, I would send the security code through a separate email service and once the user confirms that then update once on Auth0 service.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to:

1. Store old_email locally in backend db.
2. Send email warning user of change to old_email.
3. Send update email request to Auth0.
4. Send Verification email.
5. After set amount of time (ie: 24 hours) expire the verification.
6. If user session is still active, allow them to change email back to old_email, otherwise contact customer service who could reinstate old email—or instead of contacting customer service you could automatically reset email to old_email once verification token expires.

Another option to circumvent this issue would be to have a flow that would allow user to have a backup email that you store in your db, which they may verify and log in with to regain access to their account.